# Dynamically created elements lose spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div a  with two span elements:

```
<div id="layout-workspace-name">
     <span id="workspace-name">My workspace</span>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="color: white"></span>
</div>
```

Otherwise I have a Jquery code that when I click on '#workspace-name' it replace the content of '#layout-workspace':

```
$(document).on('click', '#workspace-name', function () {
    $('#layout-workspace-name').empty();
    $('#layout-workspace-name').append(
        '<input id="edit-workspace-name" value="' + workspace_name + '" type="text">'+
        '<span id="submit-name" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>'+
        '<span id="cancel-name" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>');
});
```

The problem is that when I add this code, the elements lose the spacing beetwen them, like this:
[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shfFf.png) and
[This is how the should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XcOg.png).
Here is the CSS I use for these elements:

```
#layout-workspace-name {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#workspace-name {
   font-size: 1.3em;
   color: #FFFFFF;
}

#submit-name {
  color: white;
  padding: 7px;
  background: #00D159;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#cancel-name {
  color: white;
  padding: 7px;
  background: #d10003;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Thanks for all and sorry for my english.

Comment: Just add spaces into the HTML string you're appending, at the end of each line. For example, change `type="text">' +` to `type="text"> ' +`. Note the space before the end quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML Whitespace is actually important. Elements with whitespace between them are styled differently than elements without it. In order to get your elements to display correctly you need to insert some whitespace between them. 
So if you replace your jQuery code with this it should work. All that I changed was adding a single space after each line. (additional + operators are there to make it more clear but they can be removed)

```
$('#layout-workspace-name').append(
    '<input id="edit-workspace-name" value="' + workspace_name + '" type="text">'+' '+
    '<span id="submit-name" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>'+' '+
    '<span id="cancel-name" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'+' ');
```

**Note:** While whitespace is important the quantity of that whitespace isn't so any combination of tabs returns and spaces are always treated the same.

Comment: Thanks for all Thomas, I'll try it.